# Paperclip post processing conversion does not update file_name, content_type attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, imagemagick-convert

I would like to restrict File uploads to images only, and convert them automatically to `.png`. To do so, I use this class:

```
class ImageAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file, :file_file_name, :file_content_type, :file_file_size

  validates_attachment :file,
    :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/tiff", "image/png"] }

  has_attached_file :file,
    :styles      => { :original => ["100%", :png],
                      :large    => ["500x500", :png],
                      :medium   => ["150x150", :png],
                      :thumb    => ["75x100", :png]
                    },
    :default_url => "/system/missing_thumb.png"
end
```

As I understand, the `:styles => { :original => ["100%", :png], ...}` should convert all uploaded files that pass validation to `.png` files. Therefore, I expect the following things to happen when uploading a file `example.tiff`:

1. convert the file to `.png`
2. change the file name accordingly to `example.png`
3. change the content type accordingly to `"image/png"`

Here's a spec I use:

```
it "should convert all image types to .png" do
  test_file = File.new(Rails.root + "spec/fixtures/images/test.tiff")
  attachment = ImageAttachment.create :file => test_file
  attachment.file.url.should == "some/paperclip/path/.../test.png"
  attachment.file_file_name.should == "test.png"
  attachment.file_content_type.should == "image/png"
end
```

The first assertion is true, and I can also see ImageMagick output in the terminal,
but `attachment.file_file_name` still returns `example.tiff`, and `attachment.file_content_type` returns `"image/tiff"`.

Is my assumption that paperclip automatically updates the `file_file_name` and the `file_content_type` attributes wrong?

If so, how would I best do this on my own?